# Наименьшая подпоследовательность с k инверсиями

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

Было задание реализовать по входным данным поиск "количества перестановок последовательности 1,2...n которые имеют ровно k инверсий". Я сделал через динамику, все корректно работает, но в поток вывода в итоге необходимо вывести не только количество подпоследовательностей, но и наименьшую среди них в лексикографическом порядке.

Я воспользовался для вывода следующим алгоритмом: создаем массив массив хранящий элементы 1,2,3...n в прямой последовательности, затем идем с элемента n-i до n, где i(1,n) меняя местами элементы, и за каждую замену инкрементируя счетчик, до тех пор, пока он (счетчик) не достигнет необходимого количества (k). Эта схема работает при k<=(1+2+3+...+n-2). То есть при n=4 , k=1 - 1243.

Однако при числах, которые превышают эти значения (то есть, когда, согласно алгоритму, происходит замена первого элемента) алгоритм уже не пашет n=5, k=7 - 51432, хотя есть меньшие подпоследовательности (25431, например).

Как можно его модифицировать, или же решить эту подзадачу по-другому? Была идея с полным перебором - то есть идем от прямой последовательности, постепенно ее увеличивая и проверяя, подходит ли она нам, через доп функцию - но эта реализация жрет слишком много ресурсов.

Comment: за задачку спасибо :)

Comment: Когда вы подсчитываете - сами инверсии вы случайно в явном виде не получаете? тогда достаточно просто хранить минимальную...

Comment: динамикой набирать надо... Если можно поставить минимальный и дальше всё наберётся, то надо ставить. Причём проверка дальше дальше звисит только от числа оставшихся. Кстати подсчёт числа _всех_ перестановок более сложная задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все таки обошелся без переборов, т.к. "осознал" алгоритм по которому происходит возрастание перестановок, привожу его ниже, может пригодится кому.

Точно так же выводим прямую последовательность и потом на ней меняем m[k] символ с m[n], где k изменяется на промежутке [mas.size()-2,0], n изменяется на промежутке [mas.size()-1, k+1] (проход по k - внешний цикл, по n - внутренний). За каждую замену инкремментируем счетчик, пока не найдем нужное количество.